# Reclassifying raster values in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: reclassify, google-earth-engine

I need to reclassify slope raster (val: 0-90) to 9 classes (1-9). I used this code but the output raster cannot be displayed. What did I do wrong?

```js
// Add features
var sumatera = ee.FeatureCollection("users/putraditama/sumatera");

// Add raster
var elev = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003")

// Clip elev to Sumatera boundary
var elevsmrt = elev.clip(sumatera);

// Get slope
var slopesmrt = ee.Terrain.slope(elevsmrt);

// Remap values
var slopereclass = slopesmrt
.remap([0-10,11-20,21-30,31-40,41-50,51-60,61-70,71-80,81-90],
       [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);

// Display the result.
Map.addLayer(slopesmrt, {min: 0, max :90, palette: ['black', 'white']},'slope');
Map.addLayer(slopereclass, {min: 1, max :9}, 'slopereclass');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[ee.Image.remap()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageremap) operates on individual values, not ranges of numbers like your example shows.

Given that you are trying to convert the slope values to a set of bins with equal spacing, you can just divide and set it next highest integer using [ee.Image.ceil()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageceil).

```js
// Add features.
var feature = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
             .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Switzerland'));

// Add raster.
var elev = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");

// Get slope.
var slopesmrt = ee.Terrain.slope(elev);

// Remap values.
var slopereclass = slopesmrt.divide(10).ceil();

// Display the result.
Map.addLayer(slopesmrt.clip(feature), {min: 0, max: 90, palette: ['black', 'white']},'slope');
Map.addLayer(slopereclass.clip(feature), {min: 1, max: 9, palette: ['black', 'red']}, 'slopereclass');
```

Answer (score 16):

The accepted solution addresses the very specific case at hand, and while admirably clever (kudos for that), does not answer the question, which is "How to reclass ranges in GEE".

A more general case of reclassification of ranges into user specific classes would be with conditional assignment using `where`

```
// Add features.
var feature = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017")
             .filter(ee.Filter.eq('country_na', 'Switzerland'));

// Add raster.
var elev = ee.Image("USGS/SRTMGL1_003");

// Get slope.
var slopesmrt = ee.Terrain.slope(elev);

// Remap values.
var slopereclass = ee.Image(1)
      .where(slopesmrt.gt(10).and(slopesmrt.lte(20)), 1)
      .where(slopesmrt.gt(20).and(slopesmrt.lte(30)), 2)
      .where(slopesmrt.gt(30).and(slopesmrt.lte(40)), 3)
      .where(slopesmrt.gt(40).and(slopesmrt.lte(50)), 4)
      .where(slopesmrt.gt(50).and(slopesmrt.lte(90)), 5)

// create colors for those classifications
var visparams = {
   "opacity": 1,
    "min": 1,
    "max": 5,
    "palette": ["147218", "7cb815", "f2fe2a", "ffac18", "fe3c19"]
}

Map.addLayer(slopereclass, visparams)
```

...and so on. Clearly, more to write but now I could specify any class range I want.

[image: reclassified image in earth engine]

Comment: This code seems quite dangerous in the general case as omitted values (here 0 to 10) will still be attributed a 1, without the user being aware of it...   Basically, `ee.Image(1)` acts as the "default" value. I think it would be safe to change the default value in `ee.Image(1)`, say `ee.Image(10)`, then make sure to mask it out, so that user sees omitted categories?