# Working with just one band to get a new map

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, land-cover, band, land-use

I need to create a new image using a dataset that have just one band ranging from 0 to 30. The new image that I need must have just 2 pixels value (0, 1) with 0 being deforested between 2010 - 2020 and 1 being forest.

From the original data set deforestation between 2010 - 2020 have the following values: 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 27 and 29. Forest has the value of 1.

Below I show my progress until now. However, despite be able to create the two variables that I need for the new map I don't know now how to create the new map that I need.

How can I do this?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/b2f16d163494e0e92d4b8b509c853b0e

```
var forest = prodes.eq(1)
            .clip(rr)
            .rename('Forest')
            .selfMask();

Map.addLayer(forest, {palette: 'lightgreen'}, 'Forest');

var baselineLoss = prodes.gte(9)
                    .and(prodes.lte(17))
                    .or(prodes.eq(27))
                    .or(prodes.eq(29))
                    .clip(rr)
                    .rename('Deforestation')
                    .selfMask();
                
        

Map.addLayer(baselineLoss, {palette: 'red'}, 'Baseline Deforestation (2010 - 2020)');


var totalLoss = baselineLoss.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(10000)
          .reduceRegion({
            reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
            geometry: rr,
            scale: 30,
            maxPixels: 1e13,
            });
            
print('Baseline Deforestation (ha)', totalLoss);


Map.addLayer(rr, {}, 'Reference Region');
Map.addLayer(projectArea, {}, 'Project Area');
```

---

sorry, 0 **being** deforested and 1 being forest area.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reclassifying raster values in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264000/reclassifying-raster-values-in-google-earth-engine)